# Fullstack web-hosting services

Tags: python, web, web-deployment-project, godaddy-api

I am totally new to web development, and I am trying to create a website.
From what I understand, if you create websites on Wix, Squarespace or GoDaddy, then there is a lot of security protection included. They will prevent spamming and things of that nature.

I want to create a website that has both a front-end side, and a lot of back-end python scripts.
I'm not even sure how to phrase my question properly (or if it even makes sense) since I am so new to web development, but here goes: are there web-hosting services that allow for back-end development in python? I would like the security that these sites offer and also be able to do full-stack development on them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can upload your code already written to many of the services you suggested